# How can I self join query and update in one go mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have these documents in a collection stored like this. Just focus on the relationship of parentid and id for simplicity just assume they are numbers.

I have a filter criteria coming from ui based on these documents only like text should contains some string or answers should have 3 objects atleast.

I want to match the criteria and find the parent of the document as per this parent-child relationship and update the parent with some data like `tag.push("closed")` i.e. So if id(4467) matches I want to update its parent 3853 with tag as closed.

**And one important part I cannot fetch those documents to memory and run update then**.

I have to do a updateMany query so that mongo itself handles it. Please comment if any clarification is required.

```
[{
    "id":3853,
    "text":"Whats your age",
    "answers":[],
    "parentid":1285,
    "tag":[]
},
{
    "id":4467,
    "text":"Whats your age",
    "answers":[],
    "parentid":3853,
    "tag":[]
},
{
    "id":4498,
    "text":"Whats your age",
    "answers":[],
    "parentid":3853,
    "tag":[]
},
{
    "id":4455,
    "text":"Whats your age",
    "answers":[],
    "parentid":3854,
    "tag":[]
},
{
    "id":8754,
    "text":"Whats your age",
    "answers":[],
    "parentid":3856,
    "tag":[]
}]
```

I am looking for approaches available for doing this thing without fetching the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just perform the match, lookup and update in an aggregation pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      // put your filtering criteria here
      "id": 4467
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      // your sample data is suggesting recursive structure. Feel free to replace with plain $lookup
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$parentid",
      "connectFromField": "parentid",
      "connectToField": "id",
      "as": "parent"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$parent"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$parent"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      tag: {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$tag",
          [
            "closed"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      // use $merge to update back to the collection
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pQpJqW7msXY)

Comment: It will only update the parent document and remaining document will remain as it is right?

Comment: @YashdeepHinge yes, That is why we have the `$replaceRoot