# Can aggregation pipeline be used to update documents in db?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I wrote this aggregate pipeline. I want to update the documents which match in this pipeline and get updated as per the stages. I am assuming $replaceRoot will do that. Am I incorrect.I just want to know that aggregate pipeline can update the documents or not. If yes is it a best practice or a hack. And I don't want to use the $out operator.

````
[
  { $match: { name: "awss3-metadata-loader" } },
  {
    $set: {
      tags: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [{ $type: "$tags" }, ["null"]],
          },
          then: [
            {
              k: "awss3metadataloader",
              v: "new",
            },
          ],
          else: {},
        },
      },
    },
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$$ROOT" } },
]```
````

Comment: You can use $merge` or update with a pipeline

Comment: Why don't you want to use `$out`? Agree with the comment above about your options. You are incorrect about `$replaceRoot` (it has nothing to do with modifying the documents in the collection directly). The options above are fully supported so I don't think they'd be considered a 'hack' (though, admittedly, I don't know what the definition of such in this context would be)

Comment: $out has limitations and it would limit me from sharding and all as per the documentation of $out in mongodb. I am new to mongo aggregation new to mongo db. That was my mistake I saw it here someone using replaceRoot I assumed it will update the actual document in db. is $merge a good thing? I am asking because I have no idea what are the best practices for mongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. You can use `db.collection.updateMany({<filter>}, [<pipeline>])` or `db.collection.updateOne()`

Would be

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {name: "awss3-metadata-loader"},
  [
  {
    $set: {
      tags: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [{ $type: "$tags" }, ["null"]],
          },
          then: [
            {
              k: "awss3metadataloader",
              v: "new",
            },
          ],
          else: {},
        },
      },
    },
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$$ROOT" } },
])
```

Note, the pipeline must contain only the following aggregation stages:

- `$addFields` and its alias `$set`
- `$project` and its alias `$unset`
- `$replaceRoot` and its alias `$replaceWith`

Which is the case in your example.

See [Update with an Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#std-label-updateMany-behavior-aggregation-pipeline)

Or you can use the [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) operator.

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried Only the thing is I have to some times update the parent of the document based on the parent field which would require some of the features from aggregate and $merge. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809325/how-can-i-self-join-query-and-update-in-one-go-mongodb/76814671?noredirect=1#comment135443338_76814671 This is my question where I discussed that. Thanks again.

Comment: No, this pipeline is not possible, you need to use `$merge`