# Aggregation vs Multiple fetch and update how it performs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a aggregation pipeline where the match criteria is generated dynamically by end user and the updates as well. Right now I convert the user input to a aggregation pipeline and I have some scenarios where I am using $lookup for matching parents and child. Now the thing is that collection on which I am running the aggregation is having 24m records and the aggregation is timeout due to which. And there is no scope of optimization for the pipeline because I am asked not the do too many custom changes for user input. And keep it simple.
Now my question is. Is it a best practice to increase the aggregate pipeline timeout and batch size so that It wouldn’t timeout.
Or should I change all of my approach to use multiple fetch and update calls.
And right now I am not using mongo atlas.

You can also check my other questions to understand my situation better.
[How to update all child documents of match criteria using graph lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77088492/how-to-update-all-child-documents-of-match-criteria-using-graph-lookup/77102724#77102724)
[How can I self join query and update in one go mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809325/how-can-i-self-join-query-and-update-in-one-go-mongodb)

Best Practice and Performance Comparison examples for people you have used it.